# Show EditItemTemplate in gridview when handling event

Tags: asp.net

This has got to be simple one, but I am having issues finding it.

I have a gridview which I am yanking the ObjectDataSource from and putting all the data connections in the code behind.  So now I have to manually write all the things that the Datasource handled for me (Man it does handle a lot for you).

So on my rowEditing event, I need to be able to display the EditItemTemplate.  Any Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man!  twice in one day I find the answer shortly after I post!

The step I was missing was repopulating the Grid in the event Before I set the editIndex field!  so this works

```
    protected void MyGrid_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        populateSubnetGrid();  //pulls from the Db and binds to the grid
        MyGrid.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;  //This is the selected row to edit
        MyGrid.DataBind();  //Make the edit Template show up

    }
```